# Can anyone tell me is there any method of giving seprate styles (li, ul, a) in a same CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to change (ul, li, a) of my navigation. But it also apply to my social media links. Can anyone tell me how can I give separate style to both of them.
Here are Social media links:-

```
<ul>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/Facebook.jpg"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/LinkedIn.jpg"></a> </li>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/Google.jpg"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href=""> <img src="GRProvider/Twitter.jpg"> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Here are Navigation links:-

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#"> HOME </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> ABOUT US </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> CAREER </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
</ul>
```

I'm applying this CSS which is working on both but I want give them separate styles.

```
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 25%;
}
a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #0e8393;
}
</div>
```

Comment: Use selectors, mainly classes and ids. Find more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 4):

Just do this for the navigation links only:

```
.navigation > ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation > ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 25%;
}
.navigation > ul li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.navigation ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.navigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 25%;
}

.navigation a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #0e8393;
}
```

Comment: You have typos on `.navgation` class (missing a **i**)

Comment: It may be useful to add an explanation of what the code does and why you've done it that way. It often makes it clearer to the questioner and in turn helps your answer get accepted.